# The ground state energy of the 1D XY model with staggered magnetic fields

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, fourier-transform

I am calculating the ground state energy of the 1D XY model with staggered magnetic fields,
\begin{align*}
H=J\sum_n \left[S^x_nS^x_{n+1}+S^y_nS^y_{n+1}\right]+H\sum_n(-1)^nS^z_n
\end{align*}
By applying the Jordan-Wigner transformation, the Hamiltonian can be expressed with spinless fermionic modes,
\begin{align*}
H=J\sum_n \left[c^\dagger_n c_{n+1}+c^\dagger_{n+1}c_n\right]+H\sum_n(-1)^nc^\dagger_n c_n
\end{align*}
In most cases, we use the Fourier transform to diagonalize.
I define the Fourier transform：
\begin{align*}
c_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_k e^{ikn}\eta_k,\ c^\dagger_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_k e^{-ikn}\eta^\dagger_k,
\ k=\frac{2\pi m}{N}, -\frac{N}{2}+1\le m \le \frac{N}{2}
\end{align*}
If this transformation is applied, I think the Hamiltonian looks like
\begin{align*}
H=J\sum_k \cos k \ \eta^\dagger_k\eta_k+H\sum_k\nolimits'\left[\eta^\dagger_{k}\eta_{k+\pi}+\eta^\dagger_{k}\eta_{k-\pi}\right]
\end{align*}
$\sum_k\nolimits'$ means the sum is taken so that the momentum ranges $-\pi< k,k\pm\pi\le\pi$

The problem is I don't know how to diagonalize after this or this calculation might be  wrong.
I think it can be diagonalized by the Bogoliubov transformation, but I'm not sure.

According to some literature, the ground state energy $E_0$ is given as
\begin{align*}
E_0=-\sum_k\sqrt{(J\cos k)^2+H^2}
\end{align*}
I want to know the derivation.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Did you try going to momentum space but with a unit cell of two sites? This makes more sense since the fermionic Hamiltonian you wrote is not single-site translation invariant (TI) but it is two-site TI.

Comment: It is true that if we apply the unit cell of two sites, the staggered magnetic field will apparently disappear in the Hamiltonian.
However, on the new unit cell, there are four degrees of freedom per site, and the form of interaction changes so it seems difficult to deal with.

Comment: Such things come up often in non interacting fermion problems, most famously in graphene. Check out the exact solution to the SSH model [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su–Schrieffer–Heeger_model).